Composite key with a auto-incremented column
I'm using Oracle, but this may apply to other Relational DBs, as well.
Suppose I have a table T with columns C1, C2, C3, C4. Note: C4 is numeric.
Is it possible to make C2, C3, and C4 a composite key such that when a row is being inserted and the values of C2 and C3 already exist, C4 gets auto-incremented?
Example
Say we have a table STUDENT with columns GPA, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, SEQID.
We insert a row:
INSERT INTO STUDENT (GPA, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES (3.1, 'John', 'Smith');

At this point, the contents of the table will be:



GPA
FIRSTNAME
LASTNAME
SEQID




3.1
John
Smith
1



Then, we insert another row for a student that has the same first and last name:
INSERT INTO STUDENT (GPA, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES (3.5, 'John', 'Smith');

At this point, the contents of the table will be:



GPA
FIRSTNAME
LASTNAME
SEQID




3.1
John
Smith
1


3.5
John
Smith
2



Is it possible to achieve this kind of functionality?
Thanks in advance.

why use a composite key ?  Seems like SEQID (populated by a sequence), would suffice to be used as a proper Primary Key "STUDENT_ID" .., and you avoid all the shenanigans ?

You can certainly have every insert generate a new ID, but usually this isn't what you want, as then you have no entity integrity - you can insert a hundred rows for the same student and never know what their real GPA is. Or given your example, are there two John Smiths or only one and your program wrongly inserted him again? You need some kind of natural key (maybe SSN, DL#, student ID, etc..) that you can constrain on with a UK and then if you wish add a surrogate sequence column for your PK for use with foreign key relationships.
